# Why Javascript Event Handler only works on the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have a FRONT END project, and I have an index.html file, script.js file and styles.css file. I have this simple code on my index page:

```
<div align = "center" class="Ejercicio_6">
  <label for="drop">Ingrese el número</label>
  <select name="drop" id="drop_seleclt">
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <p id="seleccion"></p>
  </div>
```

I have a javascript event handler binded with that code on my script.js file.

```
document.getElementById("drop_seleclt").onchange = function dropdown(){ document.getElementById("seleccion").innerHTML = "Has seleccionado "+  document.getElementById("drop_seleclt").value;};
```

It doesn't work, but If I do an  element on the HTML page like the next code it works.

```
 <script>
  document.getElementById("drop_seleclt").onchange = function dropdown(){ document.getElementById("seleccion").innerHTML = "Has seleccionado "+  document.getElementById("drop_seleclt").value;};
 </script>
```

And yes I have the script source link on the head of the index.html file

```
 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Is there a reason of why it works on the HTML file and not in the JS file?

Comment: "And yes I have the script source link *on the header of the index.html file*" The emphasized text is where the problem lies. `document.getElementById("drop_seleclt")` can only find elements that exist at the point in time the code runs.

Comment: I meant head sorry Im not a native english speaker

Comment: I assumed as much, but that doesn't change what i was saying. Your code is running in the header, before any elements exist for it to target.

Comment: Isn't the script always accesible for the html to use?

Comment: The script runs immediately, before any html after it has been parsed.